# Calculating sum from textboxes and displaying percentage in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have 2 forms having 250 numeric boxes and 1 single numeric box separately.
The name of first form is Q14 and second is Q15. And one single numberic box id is "HrsDetails_1".

There are 4 more numeric box which will store calculations accordingly.
Name: FirstBox_1 : Stores ( Sum of Q14 / 60 )
Name: SecBox_1  : Stores (Sum of Q15 / 60)
Name: ThirdBox_1 : Stores (FirstBox_1 / HrsDetails_1 * 100)
Name: ForthBox_1 : Stores ( Sum(FirstBox, SecondBox) / Hrsdetails_1 * 100)

I have tried below script only for id Q14_1, I want to run for Q14_1 to Q14_250. And same for Q15. Not sure if we can place in array kinda of thing and run calculation.

`<script>
    $(document).ready( function () {
    $('#Q14_1').each(function(){ 
    $(this).change(function(){ 
    var sum = 0; 
    $('#Q14_1').each(function(){ sum += $(this).val(); });
        if(sum == 0)
         $('#cchangeshr').val(sum); //FirstBox_1
         else
         $('#cchangeshr').val(sum/60); //FirstBox_1
    });
 });
});
</script>`

Comment: try a different selector. like $('#formid input') to get all inputs withing the q14 form.

Comment: @Umingo: Thanks a lot for your answer. I will try this one and let you know accordingly.